# how to delete table all row from sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am doing like these row r not deleteing from database:

```
public void deleteTable(String tablename) {
    database.execSQL("delete * from "+ tablename + ';');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tablename);`

Answer (score 2):

DeleteAll -

```
public void deleteAll()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(tablename,null,null);
    db.close();
}
```

Call this method wherever you want to delete the Database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,this will delete all rows from the table

```
public void delete() 
{
          String DELETEPASSCODE_DETAIL = "DELETE FROM tablename;";
          database.execSQL(DELETEPASSCODE_DETAIL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to delete all rows is:

```
database.execSQL("TRUNCATE TABLE " + tablename + ";");
```

Answer (score -1):

the another way is mDb.execSQL("DROP TABLE table_name");

and reCreate it by mDb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE table_name");